# Meaning of "obtain to"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What is the meaning of the English phrase "obtain to"? I came across this in newspapers today.

> From the extradition hearing kicked off for last December, and has focused largely on a series of loans from IDBI Bank to Kingfisher Airlines-from the way in which these were obtained to how- in the words of the prosecution- Mr.XYZ allegedly sought to "squirrel away" the money

Comment: Can you please provide news link or write down the content (paragraph). Many a times meaning of the word or phrase depends on the context.

Comment: The line goes like this-- From the extradition hearing kicked off for last December, and has focused largely on a series of loans from IDBI Bank to Kingfisher Airlines-from the way in which these were obtained to how- in the words of the prosecution- Mr.XYZ allegedly sought to "squirrel away" the money.

Comment: Please clarify your specific
problem or add additional
details to highlight exactly
what you need. As it's
currently written, it’s hard to
tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for
help clarifying this question.

Comment: There is no group verb "obtain to".  I believe we have here a failure to comma-unicate, as the line from the movie "Cool Hand Luke" goes, as I remember.  There should be a comma after the word "obtained", such that Partha's sentence ought to read "...from the way in which these were obtained, to how--in the words of the prosecution--..."   The comma is not absolutely required, but I think it would be a good idea, because it would indicate a slight pause, and, in my opinion, clarify the sentence.

Comment: There is an idiomatic (and somewhat starchy) "obtained to", meaning "achieved", but the above quote is not obtaining to that meaning.  Rather, as several have said, "obtained" and "to" are in two separate and relatively unrelated clauses.

Answer (score 1):

The two words are used individually.

Note that there's a *from* in the sentence before the *to*.

> **from** the way in which these were obtained **to** how (…) Mr.XYZ allegedly sought to "squirrel away" the money.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for updating description with excerpt from news article.

I googled this paragraph and found that you are talking about this article: [Vijay Mallya extradition case: Crucial hearing today](https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/companies/vijay-mallya-extradition-case-crucial-hearing-today/article24559868.ece)

Entire paragraph:

> The extradition hearing kicked off last December, and has focused largely on a series of loans from IDBI Bank to Kingfisher Airlines – from the way in which these were **obtained to** how – in the words of the prosecution – Mr Mallya allegedly sought to “squirrel away” the money. Mallya stands accused of de-frauding the consortium of public sector banks and money laundering, though during the hearings the prosecution focused mostly on the issue of fraud. 'Business failure, not fraud'Defence barrister Clare Montgomery challenged the prosecution’s contention that there was a prima facie case against Mallya, suggesting instead that it was a case of business failure rather than fraud. She also sought to portray the case against him as politically motivated – with a heated exchange at one point over the neutrality of the CBI and the decision-making processes of the Supreme Court. A defence witness also raised concerns over the conditions likely to be faced in India by Mallya in Arthur Road Jail, despite government assurances guaranteeing specific conditions at Barrack 12 of the jail.

So, we'll concentrate on first sentence of above paragraph.

> The extradition hearing kicked off last December, and has focused largely on a series of loans from IDBI Bank to Kingfisher Airlines – from the way in which these were obtained to how – in the words of the prosecution – Mr Mallya allegedly sought to “squirrel away” the money.

Here, I like to say that you don't have to read "obtained to" as a phrase. Instead, try to read lines separately as stated below.

- The extradition hearing kicked off last December
- and has focused largely on a series of loans from IDBI Bank to Kingfisher Airlines
- from the way in which these were obtained
- to how – in the words of the prosecution
- Mr Mallya allegedly sought to “squirrel away” the money.

I guess, you got the gist now!
That is the reason, it is best to provide entire context for perusal.

Here, em-dash is creating trouble to read lines in a given paragraph. 
You can read this [article](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/what/fourteen-punctuation-marks.html) on en-dash and em-dash.

> Em dash: Twice as long as the en dash, the em dash can be used in place of a comma, parenthesis, or colon to enhance readability or emphasize the conclusion of a sentence. For example, She gave him her answer — No!